# General issues when using dojo app in cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, dojo

i have a normal rich internet application which is running well in each browser, using dojo toolkit and some javascript charting library.

I want to put to make it a hybrid app on an ipad for "offline presentation issues".

So i started using cordova, created my app, added the plugins

org.apache.cordova.device
org.apache.cordova.console

And i placed my html5/css/js/images in the "www"-folder of the cordova project.

cordova emulate ios --target=iPad-2

nothing happends...

when i do a plain index.html with "hello app" it works fine.
but i dont see any errors?
is there kind of debug console?
seems also that links all must be relative and cannot be

/root/images

they must be

root/images.

are there also some linking issues?

can you give me a hint for a good start of cordova?
did i forget something?

Answer (score 0):

My **www** directory structure is  as below

```
    +--css
    +--img
    +--js
        +-dojo
            +--dojo  <dojo library>
    +--plugins
```

Below is an extract of the **index.html** file that I had created for cordova on Android.
Hope it helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

        <!-- dojo stylesheet will go here -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/dojo/dojox/mobile/themes/android/android.css" type="text/css">

        <title>ShopToDo Android App v1</title>

        <!-- Cordova Script Tag over here -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

        <!-- dojo configuration options -->
        <script>
            dojoConfig = {
                async: true,
                parseOnLoad: false
            };
        </script>
        <!-- dojo bootstrap -->
        <script src="js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

        <!-- dojo application code -->
        <!--script type="text/javascript" src="js/shoptodoAndroid6_closure4.js"></script-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shoptodoAndroid6_closure4.js"></script>


        <script>
            require([
                "dojox/mobile/parser",
                "dojo/ready",
                "dijit/registry",
                "dojo/_base/array",
                "dojo/dom",
                "dojo/dom-style",
                "dojo/dom-class",
                "dojo/dom-construct",
                "dojo/on",
                "dojo/touch",
                "dojox/mobile/compat",
                "dojo/Deferred",
                "dojo/store/Memory",
                "dojox/mobile/Button",
                "dojox/mobile/SimpleDialog",
                "dojox/mobile/ProgressIndicator",
                "dojox/mobile/ListItem",
                "dojox/mobile/RoundRectList",
                "dojox/mobile/View",
                "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView",
                "dojox/mobile/Heading",
                "dojox/mobile/RoundRectCategory",
                "dojox/mobile/RoundRect",
                "dojox/mobile/Switch",
                "dojox/mobile/CheckBox",
                "dojox/mobile/TextArea",
                "dojox/mobile/ExpandingTextArea",
                "dojox/mobile/FormLayout",
                "dojox/mobile/TextBox",
                "dojox/mobile/RadioButton",
                "dojox/mobile/Opener",
                "dojox/mobile/Tooltip",
                "dojox/mobile/TabBar",
                "dojox/mobile/TabBarButton",
                "dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton",
                "dojox/mobile/SpinWheelDatePicker",
                "dojox/mobile/SpinWheel",
                "dojox/mobile/SpinWheelSlot"
            ], function (parser, ready, registry, array, dom, domStyle, domClass,domConstruct, on, touch, compat, Deferred,
                         memory, button, dialog, progressIndicator, ListItem, RoundRectList ) {

.......

}
```